# Using a Wordpress Header Externally

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to use the Wordpress header from my [site](http://bytecraft.org/) with my PunBB forum installation in order to give my site a bit more continuity. Anyway, I've got the header stuck on the forum in a test theme I'm using (a test theme for the forum, not Wordpress), but I've run into some problems with CSS. Basically, the various CSS files from the Wordpress theme conflict with the files from the forum theme, so I can only use one set at a time.

The only suggestion I've run across is that I could use a CSS selector that covers all of the forum, as its elements all happen to fall under a specific div: `<div id="mid-inner">`. So, every tag in every CSS file would have to follow the form `#mid-inner a { color: blue }`. Unfortunately, the files I have to edit end up totalling thousands of lines. Is there any way to just apply the style sheets directly to the div, or perhaps edit the files in some CSS-specific editor that could speed up the process?

Here's a picture of what results when I use only the Wordpress CSS: [Imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OS8lH.png). You can see the correctly-displayed Wordpress site and PunBB forum via the navigation links at the first link I gave you.

Thanks a lot for the help—please let me know if I need to provide more details; my brain is a bit fried right now, so I probably missed something.

Comment: This isn't a systems administration question, it is a web design question, and as such is off-topic for Server Fault.

Comment: My apologies. Would Super User or Stack Overflow be more appropriate?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the topic of either of those sites to say for certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should probably be asked on the [Wordpress Stack Exchange site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks, but they were less than helpful (i.e. no response whatsoever).